# How can I persuade/bribe animals to do simple tasks?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, unearthed-arcana, animals

As [a Beast Conclave Ranger](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_RevisedRanger.pdf), how can I persuade animals to gather (simple) information, spy on somebody, or do simple tasks?

What spells or skills could I use?

I would like options that don't rely on use of Persuasion or any Charisma skill.

I have many RP ideas, but I would like to know how to achieve this mechanically using the rules.

Comment: Spying on someone is not a simple task, especially for an animal. Can you provide a specific example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can use your bond to make your animal companion spy for you**

Animal Companion

> At 3rd level, you learn to use your magic to create a powerful bond with a creature of the natural world...

Companion’s Bond

> The companion obeys your commands as best it can.

Other than that, I personally don't know how an animal could be made to spy for someone, without magic, considering the wild animal intelligence stats are pretty low. And the rest would be hard to persuade to help you without some sort of persuasion.

*"What about the Animal Handling skill?"*

Since that skill is wisdom based it could very well solve your problem, except:

> **Animal Handling.** When there is any question whether you can calm down a domesticated animal, keep a mount from getting spooked, or intuit an animal’s intentions, the GM might call for a Wisdom (Animal Handling) check. You also make a Wisdom (Animal Handling) check to control your mount when you attempt a risky maneuver.

As you can see this is more instict and intuition based check. That's the reason persuading is CHA based and this is WIS. Wouldn't exactly be RAW but it could be ruled to use for persuading animals.

With magic you have a better chance of finding a solution to your problem. Here are some ranger spells that would help:

- **Animal Friendship** *PHB 212*
- **Speak With Animals** *PHB 277* (Also persuasion so maybe not.)
- **Conjure Animals** *PHB 225* (Up to an hour though.)
- **Speak With Plants** *PHB 277*

I'm sure there could be even more magical ways to accomplish similar things, you should give your spell list a look.

Comment: The Circle of the Shepherd Druid's Speech of the Woods feature does let you converse with beasts: "This ability doesn’t grant you any special friendship with beasts, though you can combine this ability with gifts to curry favor with them as you would with any nonplayer character." So that might be another method.

Answer (score 0):

Persuading people to do things is always going to be a Charisma check.  Persuading animals might be a Charisma (Animal Handling) check, which would let you add proficiency, but that's about it.

You can, however, *force* animals to do stuff for you via magic.  The first level spell *Animal Friendship* is intended to more or less do what you want here (gives an animal the charmed condition), possibly augmented by the first level spell *Beast Bond* (lets you talk to it telepathically, requires concentration).  The first level spell *Speak with Animals* does *not* do what you want, because it gives you no supernatural power to force animals to serve you against their will but rather just lets you talk with and potentially convince them of stuff (e.g. via actually talking to them in-game and/or charisma checks).

The second level spell *Animal Messenger* does a pretty good job of forcing animals to do a single specific task (deliver messages for you); it requires no saving throw and lasts 24 hours + 48 hours per level you upcast it.

The 3rd-level spell *Conjure Animals* lets you make things that *look* like animals, but are actually eldritch abominations pulled forth from the feywild to serve you.  They are friendly to you and your companions and obey your verbal commands, and they might even not be magically forced to do so.  They definitely aren't animals, though.  The 4th-level spell *Conjure Woodland Beings* is similar except the fey show their true form (and also behave as mindless servitors unless you command them otherwise).

There are lots of spells not on the Ranger list that help with this, but the most notable is probably the *friends* cantrip.  The *friends* spell uses magical compulsion to give you advantage on Charisma checks with a creature for 1 minute (requires Concentration), but normally has the very big drawback that those so influenced magically become hostile to you at the end of the spell and know that you influenced their mood via magic.  Ordinarily, this means that they tell everybody else that you did that, and now everyone hates you and the town will probably kill you.  With animals, this means that just that one particular animal hates you and might attack you, which isn't really that big a deal.  Thus acquiring a level of a class that grants the *friends* cantrip might make your mass enslavement plans for animals much easier to accomplish with lowish Charisma.